# AWS EKS Self managed EC2 instances Patching

Tags: amazon-eks

We are running a self managed EC2 instances in the EKS Cluster.  While upgrading control plane is managed by AWS, the worker nodes are self managed. For running security updates and patches, we use the latest optimized AMI and role out the new instances. Some of these are manual effort, what is the best automated approach that you are following to update/patch those self managed EC2 worker nodes?

Steps that we follow:

- Look for the latest optimized AMI version released by AWS
- Update the Launch configuration with new AMI
- Scale up nodes with New AMI
- Seamlessly transfer pods from old to new nodes
- scale down and delete the old nodes.

The issue here after we update with new optimized AMI, we still find out some security updates that are listed during scanning those instances.

Answer (score 0):

> Some of these are manual effort, what is the best **automated approach**

I suggest to have a look at [Managed Node Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-groups.html) since that is an automated approach for the lifecycle management that you are doing.

> Nodes run using the latest Amazon EKS optimized AMIs in your AWS account while node updates and terminations gracefully drain nodes to ensure that your applications stay available.

> All managed nodes are provisioned as part of an Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling group that is managed for you by Amazon EKS. All resources including the instances and Auto Scaling groups run within your AWS account. Each node group uses the Amazon EKS optimized Amazon Linux 2 AMI and can run across multiple Availability Zones that you define.

Comment: In my opinion, in regards to updating AMI with new releases, AMI behaviour is similar in case of EKS manages NG & Self-managed NG, in both cases we have to update AMIs manually.